# Using soundcloud HTML5 player on https page

Tags: html, ssl, https, soundcloud

Trying to embed the html5 soundcloud player to work on a secure page without warnings.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F27710389&amp;show_artwork=true&amp;color=444444&amp;show_comments=false&amp;height=140"></iframe>
```

Still the player is loading the tracks/cover images from a non-secure http domain, which throws warnings.
Is it possible?

Edit: Contacted soundcloud dev team about the issue and they are looking into it. Will post back.

Thnx

Comment: Hi There. Is this still happening? It looks like the dev team may have solved the problem but I wanted to verify.

Comment: Haven't heard back from the soundcloud team yet. But the player is still causing warnings on my secure page by loading the avatar from http://

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed now.

Comment: not fixed here. in chrome: `Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://illmagic.revillini.com/ from frame with URL https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/17124095&auto_play=false&show_artwork=true&color=ff7700. The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match.`